# Adding \n characters inside outline.paragraphs.items[0].insertRichTextAsSibling('Before', code);

Tags: office-js, onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to add text with \n line break characters inside OneNote's(Web) paragraph via

> outline.paragraphs.items[0].insertRichTextAsSibling('Before', text);

the problem is that these newline characters aren't visible in one note. They are visible after page refresh though. Am I missing something?

Gif that shows behavior.
http://giphy.com/gifs/l3q2C8LhETxg9KWtO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [insertHtmlAsSibling](https://github.com/Microsoft/Office-js-docs_de-de/blob/master/reference/onenote/paragraph.md#inserthtmlassiblinginsertlocation-string-html-string).

```
outline.paragraphs.items[0].insertHtmlAsSibling('Before', "row1<br>row2<br>row3<br>row4<br>);
```

With that function, you'd be able to create lists, tables, text with special fonts like bold, etc.

Answer (score 1):

\n is not supported character 
You could do following.

```
var row1Text = outline.paragraphs.items[0].insertRichTextAsSibling('Before', 'row 1');
var row2Text = row1Text.paragraph.insertRichTextAsSibling('After', 'row 2');
var row3Text = row2Text.paragraph.insertRichTextAsSibling('After', 'row 3');
var row4Text = row3Text.paragraph.insertRichTextAsSibling('After', 'row 4');
```